# C# - How will the value displayed on textbox will be displayed once the "delete" button is clicked?

Tags: c#, forms

I am creating a POS system. I only know how to display the data that are always submitted. But.. when I try to delete a certain product from the listview, the value displayed on the text box *doesn't deduct*. **How can I implement the codes from it?**

Here is the code..

```
public frm_order() {
 InitializeComponent();

 listView1.View = View.Details;
 listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

 listView1.Columns.Add("Product Name", 150);
 listView1.Columns.Add("Quantity", 100);
 listView1.Columns.Add("Price", 100);
}

private void add(String name, String qty, String price) {
 String[] row = {
  name,
  qty,
  price
 };

 ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);

 listView1.Items.Add(item);
}

int qty;
double price;
double subtotal;
double tax;
double total;
double vat = 0.12;

private void btn_choco_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 txt_name.Text = "Choco Lover";
 txt_price.Text = "65.00";
 txt_quantity.Text = "1";
 price = 65.00;
}
private void btn_tutti_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 txt_name.Text = "Tutti Frutti";
 txt_price.Text = "65.00";
 txt_quantity.Text = "1";
 price = 65.00;
}
private void btn_black_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 txt_name.Text = "Black Forest";
 txt_price.Text = "75.00";
 txt_quantity.Text = "1";
 preprice = 75.00;
}
private void btn_vanilla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 txt_name.Text = "Vanilla Sky";
 txt_price.Text = "65.00";
 txt_quantity.Text = "1";
 price = 65.00;
}
private void btn_ube_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 txt_name.Text = "Ube My Bebe";
 txt_price.Text = "65.00";
 txt_quantity.Text = "1";
 preprice = 65.00;
}
private void btn_smores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 txt_name.Text = "Smore's Pa More";
 txt_price.Text = "65.00";
 txt_quantity.Text = "1";
 price = 65.00;
}
private void btn_cookie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 txt_name.Text = "Cookie Monster";
 txt_price.Text = "65.00";
 txt_quantity.Text = "1";
 price = 65.00;
}
private void btn_rainbow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 txt_name.Text = "Rainbow Dreamland";
 txt_price.Text = "75.00";
 txt_quantity.Text = "1";
 price = 75.00;
}

private void btn_confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 qty = Convert.toInt32(txt_quantity.Text);
 add(txt_name.Text, txt_quantity.Text, txt_price.Text);

 subtotal = price * qty;
 txt_subtotal.Text = subtotal.ToString();
 tax = subtotal * vat;
 txt_tax.Text = tax.ToString();
 total = subtotal + total;
 txt_total.Text = total.ToString();

 txt_name.Text = "";
 txt_quantity.Text = "";
 txt_price.Text = "";
}

private void delete() {
 if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.OK) {
  listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedIndices[0]);
  listView1.Refresh();

  txt_name.Text = "";
  txt_quantity.Text = "";
  txt_price.Text = "";
 }
}

private void btn_del_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 delete();
}

private void update() {
 listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text = txt_name.Text;
 listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text = txt_quantity.Text;
 listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text = txt_price.Text;

 txt_name.Text = "";
 txt_quantity.Text = "";
 txt_price.Text = "";
}
private void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 update();
}

private void btn_clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 listView1.Items.Clear();

 txt_name.Text = "";
 txt_quantity.Text = "";
 txt_price.Text = "";
}

private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
 txt_name.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
 txt_quantity.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
 txt_price.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
}

private void btn_payment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 frm_payment pay = new frm_payment();
 pay.Show();
}

private void frm_order_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

}

private void txt_quantity_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
 if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.')) {
  e.Handled = true;
 }
}
```

Also, how would I implement the code that will display the total of "ordered product"? hope you can answer me.

Comment: You have to recalculate the total each time you deduct or add to the list; so you need to call `update()` after you `delete()`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid actually, the update() there is for the changes in the entered data in the listview, especially in quantity.

Answer (score 0):

after deleting from listView you need to call update() each time. Call listView1.Refresh() after deleting like below (I tested its working for me)

```
 listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedIndices[0]);
 listView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: but the update() there is for the changes of data in the entered product :3

Comment: Will the price displayed won the textbox will also be refreshed?

Comment: plz try and see

Comment: It does delete the "item" on the listview, but, the value on the "textbox" that shows the total doesn't deduct. How should I implement the code for it?

Comment: I have these variables: **subtotal**, **total**, and **tax**. Every each of them are declared called in the confirm button and converted toString() to display values on the textboxes. But, when I delete an item on the listview, there are no changes that happened. What should I do?

P.S. I edited the codes in the question above. Thanks.